# What flags are enabled by -XX:+AggressiveOpts on Sun JRE 1.6u20?

Tags: performance, jvm, java

From Sun JRE [performance tuning whitepaper](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html#section4.2.4), `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` flag is described as:

> Turns on point performance
>   optimizations that are expected to be
>   on by default in upcoming releases.
>   The changes grouped by this flag are
>   minor changes to JVM runtime compiled
>   code and not distinct performance
>   features (such as BiasedLocking and
>   ParallelOldGC). This is a good flag to
>   try the JVM engineering team's latest
>   performance tweaks for upcoming
>   releases. Note: this option is
>   experimental! The specific
>   optimizations enabled by this option
>   can change from release to release and
>   even build to build. You should
>   reevaluate the effects of this option
>   with prior to deploying a new release
>   of Java.

My performance tests indicate that using `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` actually helps my application, but since this is marked as experimental I want to be careful with it (I have been burned by it in the past). So, I want to know what flags are enabled by `-XX:+AggressiveOpts` on 1.6u20. Typically I do this by looking at the method `Arguments::set_aggressive_opts_flags()` in `hotspot/src/share/vm/runtime/arguments.cpp` file, but I am unable to find the sources to 1.6u20 at http://download.java.net/jdk6/source/.

- Is there some other way to figure out what flags `-XX:+AggressiveOpts`
  enable?
- Where can I get sources to 1.6u20 release?

Comment: Does the flag also influence use of alt-rt.jar versus rt.jar? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6979890/difference-of-hashmap-in-alt-rt-jar-and-rt-jar

Answer (score 42, accepted):

To check it for particular release:

```
java -XX:-AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version > no_agg
java -XX:+AggressiveOpts -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version > agg
```

And then make diff (`diff -U0 no_agg agg`).

For example, jdk 1.7.0_51:

```
-     bool AggressiveOpts                           := false           {product}
+     bool AggressiveOpts                           := true            {product}

-     intx AutoBoxCacheMax                           = 128             {C2 product}
+     intx AutoBoxCacheMax                           = 20000           {C2 product}

-     intx BiasedLockingStartupDelay                 = 4000            {product}
+     intx BiasedLockingStartupDelay                 = 500             {product}

-     bool UseFPUForSpilling                         = false           {C2 product}
+     bool UseFPUForSpilling                         = true            {C2 product}
```

Jdk 1.8.0:

```
-     bool AggressiveOpts                           := false           {product}
+     bool AggressiveOpts                           := true            {product}

-     intx AutoBoxCacheMax                           = 128             {C2 product}
+     intx AutoBoxCacheMax                           = 20000           {C2 product}

-     intx BiasedLockingStartupDelay                 = 4000            {product}
+     intx BiasedLockingStartupDelay                 = 500             {product}

-     bool EliminateAutoBox                          = false           {C2 product}
+     bool EliminateAutoBox                          = true            {C2 product}

-     bool UseFPUForSpilling                         = false           {C2 product}
+     bool UseFPUForSpilling                         = true            {C2 product}
```

Comment: this works only on VMs which have `-XX:+PrintFlagsFinal`; nonetheless, I am marking this as the answer because it answered my original question and might be useful to others.

Answer (score 6):

Check out this blog post to find out without needing to dive into the code. http://q-redux.blogspot.com/2011/01/inspecting-hotspot-jvm-options.html